# React component not re-rendering with state update

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm having some issues with a React component not updating, even though I can confirm that the state is being updated.

Link to Codepen is here: https://codepen.io/paalpwmd/full/WNveejG

```
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
    }   
  }


  render(){
      return(
        <div>
          <a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet" id="tweet-quote">Tweet me</a>
        </div>
      )
    }
}

class QuoteBody extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.refreshQuote = this.refreshQuote.bind(this);
    this.state = { quote: "", author: "", quotePos: 0 };
  } 


refreshQuote() {
    let n = Math.floor(Math.random() * (120 - 0 + 1) + 0);
    this.setState({
    quotePos: n
    });
  console.log(this.state.quotePos)
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div>
      <button id="new-quote" onClick={this.refreshQuote}>New Quote!</button>
      <div id="text"> 
      <p>{this.state.quote}</p>
        </div>
            <div id="author">
        <p>{"- " + this.state.author}</p>
        </div>
        <TwitterButton />
        </div>
    )
  }
componentDidMount() {
    fetch("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/camperbot/5a022b72e96c4c9585c32bf6a75f62d9/raw/e3c6895ce42069f0ee7e991229064f167fe8ccdc/quotes.json")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(
        (result) => {
          let i = this.state.quotePos;
          this.setState({
            quote: result.quotes[i].quote,
            author: result.quotes[i].author
          });
        },
        (error) => {
          this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
            error
          });
        }
      )
  }
}

const QuoteBox = document.getElementById("quote-box")
ReactDOM.render(<QuoteBody />, QuoteBox);
```

I'm pretty new to React, so I'm not entirely sure what I'm doing wrong, so I'm sharing the whole project.

I'm expecting the QuoteBody component to update when refreshQuote is run, but it does not.

Upon some research, the best I could gather is that people have the same problem when doing things asynchronously, but I haven't found a clear solution that solves my exact problem (most of the help I've found is syntax errors, which I *think* I'm free of.

Thank you for your help in advance - I sincerely appreciate it!

Comment: What exactly isn't updating?

Comment: Sorry! Left the crucial part out - updated my post. to reflect that.

I'm expecting the QuoteBody component to update when refreshQuote is run, but it does not.

Comment: in refreshQuote(), you need to make API request again.  request componentDidMount will made only once.

Comment: I guess you solved your problem but here is an helpful advice: When you are calling `this.setState` you need to pass the existing state with the spread operator (`...`) and pass whatever other new values you want to pass afterwards otherwise you would lose them. Like this: `this.setState({ ...this.state, quotePos: n  })`

Comment: @SametM. No, the class component's `setState` method will merge the update-object into the previous state so there's no need to do that. It's needed when using objects with the setter returned from the `useState` hook but not in a class component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `componentDidMount` callback only runs when the component is mounted in the DOM, which is the first time you load the page in your case. Subsequent changes to state will not cause it to be mounted again. Since all you're changing is the `quotePos` part of the state the `quote` and `author` parts will not change, so the parts that use those won't be updated on the following render.

You'll probably want to keep the entire result-set from the fetch you do in `componentDidMount` in state and read the correct one using `quotePos` in your render.

Answer (score 1):

You should call `fetch` and updating logic in the `refreshQuote` function. Cause that is what using `this.setState` function. `componentDidMount` will get called once your component is loaded the first time.

componentDidMount is like initializing components with the state. Then when the user will interact with component you can pass the events from child component to parent using function. In the above case, the function can be `refreshQuote`.

One more thing you are missing to bound `this` to component. Make `refreshQuote` arrow function.

You can define a custom function to which will update the state. Else add fetch logic to `refreshQuote` function.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much! I made another fetch call in the refreshQuote body.

```
class TwitterButton extends React.Component{
constructor(props){
    super(props)
  }


  render(){
      return(
        <div>
          <a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet" id="tweet-quote">Tweet me</a>
        </div>
      )
    }
}

class QuoteBody extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.refreshQuote = this.refreshQuote.bind(this);
    this.state = { quote: "", author: "", quotePos: 0 };
  } 


refreshQuote() {
  fetch("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/camperbot/5a022b72e96c4c9585c32bf6a75f62d9/raw/e3c6895ce42069f0ee7e991229064f167fe8ccdc/quotes.json")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(
        (result) => {
          let i = this.state.quotePos;
          let n = Math.floor(Math.random() * (120 - 0 + 1) + 0);
          this.setState({
            quote: result.quotes[n].quote,
            author: result.quotes[n].author
          });
        },
        (error) => {
          this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
            error
          });
        }
      )
  }


  render(){
    return(
      <div>
      <button id="new-quote" onClick={this.refreshQuote}>New Quote!</button>
      <div id="text"> 
      <p>{this.state.quote}</p>
        </div>
            <div id="author">
        <p>{"- " + this.state.author}</p>
        </div>
        <TwitterButton />
        </div>
    )
  }
componentDidMount() {
    fetch("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/camperbot/5a022b72e96c4c9585c32bf6a75f62d9/raw/e3c6895ce42069f0ee7e991229064f167fe8ccdc/quotes.json")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(
        (result) => {
          let n = Math.floor(Math.random() * (120 - 0 + 1) + 0);
          this.setState({
            quote: result.quotes[n].quote,
            author: result.quotes[n].author
          });
        },
        (error) => {
          this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
            error
          });
        }
      )
  }
}

const QuoteBox = document.getElementById("quote-box")
ReactDOM.render(<QuoteBody />, QuoteBox);
```

Comment: you should make api calls only once in ```componentDidMount```. state object should be like ```this.state = {quotes:[] , activeQuote:0}``` . After fetching data from api , quotes array should be updated and on ```refreshQuote``` only activeQuote value should be updated with a random value. In render method , use activeQuote array index to show current quote and author.